# Gulp copy all files within a subdirectory with a given name

Tags: gulp

I have a gulp script which is supposed to copy some dll's in sub directories, if those files have the ending with for instace .Plugin. So I have this structure in my solution:

[image]

Now I want to copy all of my assemblies with name ending with `.Plugin.dll` up to the folder `Plugins` right under `Host`. This is my gulp script so far:

```
gulp.task('pluginsCopy', function (cb) { 
    gulp.src('.\/**/bin/Debug/*.Plugins')
        .pipe(newer("bin/Debug/Plugins/"))    
        .pipe(gulp.dest("bin/Debug/Plugins/"))
});
```

As you can see, I dont have that much experience with gulp, but could someone please give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: one question, why your _gulp.dest_ is *bin/Debug/Plugins/* and not *Host/Plugins*?

Comment: @calazans Sorry my bad: Updated the image showing the folder structure

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');

    var bases = {
     app: 'MySolution/',
     dist: 'MySolution/bin/Debug/Plugins',
    };

    var paths = {
     text: '**/*.dll.txt' 
    };

    // Copy all other files to dist directly
    gulp.task('copy',  function() {
     // Copy txt
     gulp.src(paths.text, {cwd: bases.app})
     .pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist)); 
    });
gulp.task('default', ['copy']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I didnt work for me. Check my answer as I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
gulp.task('pluginCopy', function (cb) {
    gulp.src('../*Plugin/bin/Debug/*.Plugin.dll')
        .pipe(newer("bin/Debug/Plugins/"))    
        .pipe(rename({ dirname: '' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("bin/Debug/Plugins/"))
});
```